# Problem with Kafka deserialization Python

Tags: python, avro

I new in Kafka and Python but I should create consumer:)

I created simple consumer and got result, but the data in Kafka is store in Avro that's why I need to make deserialization.

I tried variant like this

```
import os
from confluent_kafka import Consumer
from confluent_kafka.serialization import SerializationContext, MessageField
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro import AvroDeserializer


if __name__ == "__main__":

    class test(object):

        def __init__(self,test_id=None,dep=None,descr=None,stor_key=None,pos=None,time_dt=None):
            self.test_id = test_id
            self.dep = dep
            self.descr = descr
            self.stor_key = stor_key
            self.pos = pos
            self.time_dt = time_dt


def dict_to_klf(obj, ctx):

   if obj is None:
        return None

   return test(test_id=obj['test_id'],
                    dep=obj['dep'],
                    descr=obj['descr'],
                    stor_key=obj['stor_key'],
                    pos=obj['pos'],
                    time_dt=obj['time_dt'])

schema = "descr.avsc"

path = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
with open(f"{path}\\{schema}") as f:
        schema_str = f.read()
        
sr_conf = {'url': ':8081'}
schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient(sr_conf)     


avro_deserializer = AvroDeserializer(schema_registry_client,
                                         schema_str,
                                         dict_to_klf)   

consumer_config = {
        "bootstrap.servers": "com:9092",
        "group.id": "descr_events",
        "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
                  }

consumer = Consumer(consumer_config)

consumer.subscribe(['descr'])

while True:
        msg = consumer.poll(1)
        if msg is None:
          continue

         user = avro_deserializer(message.value, SerializationContext(topic, MessageField.VALUE))
   
        print(msg.topic())
        print("-------------------------")
```

And got error

```
fastavro._schema_common.SchemaParseException: Default value <undefined> must match schema type: long
```

SCHEMA_PATH = "descr.avsc" looks like

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "klf",
    "namespace": "test_ns",
    "fields": [ 
        {
            "name": "descr",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "undefined"
        },
        {
            "name": "test_id",
            "type": "long",
            "default": "undefined"
        },
        {
            "name": "dep",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "undefined"
        },
        {
            "name": "stor_key",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "undefined"
        },
        {
            "name": "time_dt",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "undefined"
        },
        {
            "name": "pos",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "undefined"
        }
    ]
    
}
```

What will I need to change to get the result with data?

Comment: We won't be able to answer this without knowing how the data is produced. More specifically, you get empty strings because the schema doesn't match the binary content of the data (or the produced data is simply empty). For example, if used the Confluent Schema Registry, then you should use their Deserializer logic (which does not need a schema file) rather than write your own

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know how the data is loaded, I'm only trying to read it.
and yes, Confluent is used.
I tried to follow this example [link](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro_consumer.py) but it also uses a schema file. 
Maybe you will recommend other sample?

Comment: You can download the AVSC directly from the registry over HTTP in code rather than need any local file. But you do need to use the avro_deserializer from that example

Comment: When I was trying use avro_deserializer `avro_deserializer = AvroDeserializer(schema_registry_client,
                                         schema_str,
                                         dict_to_zling)   `
and `user = avro_deserializer(msg.value(), SerializationContext(msg.topic(), MessageField.VALUE))` I get error "fastavro._schema_common.SchemaParseException: Default value <undefined> must match schema type: long" but AVSC not include "Default value"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempt

Comment: Without seeing your producer schema, we won't know what your data should look like. The schema you've shown has no long fields, so that error doesn't make sense to me

Comment: my avsc file looks like producer schema

Comment: Okay, so `"undefined"` is a string, and not a valid default value for a numerical `long` field (`test_id`). Perhaps you want to use `-1`, or `0`? Or make it an actual string, and handle parsing later? Removed Kafka tags since your error seems only related to Avro issues

Comment: I changed "undefined" to 0 
`{
   "name": "test_id",
   "type": "long",
   "default": 0
  },`
and got other error 'schema_registry.client.errors.ClientError: Incompatible schema'

"Or make it an actual string, and handle parsing later?" - unfortunately I didn`t understand

Comment: You get "incompatible schema" because you cannot change a string to a long in the registry. You need to delete any existing schemas from the registry to fix this. Otherwise, you need `"name": "test_id", "type": "string", "default": "undefined"`, then you would use `test_id=str(obj['test_id'])`

Comment: I changed the schema but got other problems, program work but doesnt show any result or error(( 

Thats why I checked to read data from topics without deserialization. When I use `from confluent_kafka import Consumer` data in this topic doesn`t read it, if I will chose some other topics I will get data but not for all topics.

Comment: Thats why I changed the library on `from pykafka import KafkaClient` and it works for topic `descr`, but when I added deserialization `import os
from confluent_kafka.serialization import SerializationContext, MessageField
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro import AvroDeserializer`
but I got the error 
`user = avro_deserializer(message.value(), SerializationContext(message.topic(), MessageField.VALUE))
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable`

Comment: I don't think pykafka is maintained anymore... Your error here is because message.value isn't a function. Neither is topic

Comment: unfortunately the fixes did not help, there are problems with connecting to Kafka using confluent_kafka

Comment: Please [edit] your post with updated code and the error

Comment: edited only ` user = avro_deserializer(message.value, SerializationContext(topic, MessageField.VALUE))` 
and I tried to connect  to kafka, program run but anything happened 
I think it is problem with our internal kafka because when I tried to connect using Java all be fine.
But I got the same errors:
It is error when I tried read topic without problem with `long`
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!

Comment: and
With type `long` problem
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 1429Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Invalid default for field line_id: "undefined" not a "long"

And I tried to edit  Schema Registry, but it does not help, because data in kafka have link to Schema Registry and when I changed Schema Registry it is didnt help because new Schema has other id.
Also I not owner data and I didnt create Producer for load data

Comment: Please show descr-value schema from the registry rather than your local file. As mentioned before, `undefined` string isn't a valid default for a long id field. If anyone produced that into the registry, then you'll not be able to consume it since that's an invalid schema, and if you're seeing `Unknown magic byte`, this means you're trying to deserialize data that is not Avro, so again, bad data exists in the topic from some producer

Comment: I downloaded this schema from schema-registry. 
for reading this topic need to use `key` and `value`, and `value` it is descr.avsc and `key`  =  string
Sorry, I just found out about this today.

Comment: Not sure what else to tell you. `test_id` cannot have a `long` type, for reasons I already explained. The fix would be to set this as a `string` type instead, or change the default value to an actual number.

Comment: I have found other method that works for me.
I use AvroConsumer

Comment: Feel free to post a complete answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method helped me

```
from confluent_kafka import avro, KafkaError, KafkaException,OFFSET_BEGINNING
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroConsumer
from confluent_kafka.cimpl import TopicPartition
import json

sr_url = ":8081"
kafka_broker_url = ":9092"
kafka_group_id = "group_id"

consumer = AvroConsumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': kafka_broker_url,
    'group.id': kafka_group_id,
    'schema.registry.url': sr_url,
    'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'}
})


topic = 'topic'
partitions = 0

tp = TopicPartition(topic, partitions, OFFSET_BEGINNING)
consumer.assign([tp])
consumer.seek(tp)


try:
    while True:
        msg = consumer.poll(1.0)
        if msg is None:
            continue
        if msg.error():
            if msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                print('End of partition event received for partition {}:{}'.format(msg.topic(), msg.partition()))
            else:
                raise KafkaException(msg.error())
        else:
            value = msg.value()
            print(value)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    consumer.close()
```